# Are Static Fields thread Safe

Tags: c#, wcf, static, thread-safety, static-members

We have a Static field in a abstract class

ABSTRACT CLASS :-

```
public abstract class BaseController
{

 private static string a;
 private static string b;

 protected abstract SomeArray[] DoSomeThing();

}
```

And a derived class

```
public class Controller1:BaseController
{

      protected override SomeArray[] DoSomthing()
      {
        //////
        In this method we are setting the static variables with different values
      }

}
```

We also have a class which is starting threads

```
public class SomeClass 
{

  public SomeClass()
  {
    \\ we are setting the controller we want to call, i mean to decide which base class to call 
  }

   public void Run()
   {
     Thread t  = new Thread(StartThread);
    t.Start();

   }

  public void StartThread()
  {
     _controller.DoSomeThing();
  }

}
```

All the above service is in a WCF service, and the same client tries to call multiple times which means we have multiple threads running at the same time, we have seen issues where the static variable which we are setting and using that for some DB update process is sometimes having wrong values

I have read some blogs which says static fields are not thread safe, Can some body please help me understand what could be going wrrong in our code and why we are having some incorrect values passed to the DB.

Comment: You need an example. otherwise the answer simply is: Setting a static variable is non blocking (not thread safe) and not necessarily atomic (not thread safe).

Comment: How you do this appropriately is entirely dependant on what you're actually doing.  Without knowing what you're doing, we couldn't possibly comment on the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Servy, I am actually trying to run two scheduled tasks, which are exposed as OperationContract on a WCF service, from a windows service, Since the same windows service is trying to hit the Same service at same time in parallel and we have static fields from the base abstract class it is causing the issue of wrong values passed to the DB

Comment: What is the type of `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a static field or member is shared among all instances of that class, only one instance of that field or member exisits; thus, it is not thread safe.

You have two options, either to synchronize the access (basically, using Monitor class) to that field or to use the ThreadStaticAttribute on that field.

However, i advice to reorganize your class hierarchy so that each class has its own instance of the field or member.

**Please note that if there are multiple threads working on the same instance of the class Controller, then we go back to the same problem and you should synchronize access to that instance field.**

Good Luck

Comment: I have understood your suggestion right, you are suggesting me that i change the static variable in the basecontroller class to a instance variable,  and set that Instance variable in each of the derived class so that i have the right values passed to the DB always

Comment: @CSharped, Exactly. And i think it is the best way in order to avoid the unnecessary thread synchronzation.

Comment: So with PerCall InstanceContextMode set on the WCF servive and Instance Variable on the BaseController should fix the issue? I will try it and let u know how it goes

Comment: Your first sentence implies that instance members _are_ inherently thread-safe. But of course this is not true. You should edit your answer so that it doesn't provide misleading information.